# Does $f_n(x)=e^{-nx}$ converge uniformly to the zero function on the interval $(0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Consider $f_n(x)=e^{-nx}$.

I am wondering whether it converges uniformly to the zero function on the interval $(0,1].$ I can prove that it certainly converges uniformly to the zero function on any interval $[b,1]$ where $b>0.$ But I am just not sure about the case $(0,1].$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/)

Answer (score 3):

You are right ! $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to the zero function on $(0,1]$. This can be seen by

$f_n(1/n)=1/e$  for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** set $x_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{1}{n}\in(0,1]$ for all $n\geq 1$.

What is $f_n(x_n)$? What does that tell you about $\sup_{x\in(0,1]} \lvert f_n(x)\rvert$?

Comment: But it is indeed true that $f_n$ converges to the zero function on the interval $[b,1]$ where $b>0$, right?

Comment: Yes. And the reason the above $x_n$ is not a counterexample for it to happen is that for any fixed $b>0$, you end up having $x_n\in(0,b)$ (outside $[b,1]$) when $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

No. For if it did, then it would be the case that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies that $f_n(x)=e^{-nx} < \varepsilon$ for all $x\in (0,1]$. However, let $\varepsilon = 0.5$, and given $n$, let $x_n = \frac{\ln (4/3)}{n}\in (0,1]$. Then $f_n(x_n)=0.75 > 0.5$. This is to say, there exists $\varepsilon$ such that for all $N$ we have an $m>N$ so that there exists $x$ such that $f_m(x) > \varepsilon$. Thus, the sequence does not converge uniformly.

Comment: I think you mean $4/3>0.5$ instead of $0.75>0.5$.

Comment: $f_n(x_n) = \exp(-n\ln(4/3)/n) = \exp(-\ln(4/3)) = \exp(\ln(3/4)) = 3/4$

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approach uniform convergence problems:

No matter how large $n$ be, there will be some $x$, close to zero, so that $-nx$ is still small in size, and thus $exp(-nx)$ is not close to zero, yet. This proves that for different $x$ the convergence happens at a different $n$ -- i.e. not uniformly converging.